# Zend Framework Database Transaction - Can't rollback

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, transactions

Alright, let me get this out of the way first.  My question is similar to this:
[Cannot rollback transaction in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083857/cannot-rollback-transaction-in-zend-framework)

My tables are always innoDB, always. I've checked the table in question and it is indeed innoDB.  On to the problem..

I have a database instance, and model instances running through this transaction hitting the same database:

```
$db->beginTransaction();

try { 
  // Run an insert
  $model_record->insert(array('single_item' => 'its value'));

  // More logic, and run an update.
  $model_record->this_value = 'that';

  // Save it
  $model_record->save();

  //Commit the transaction
  $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {

  // It finds the rollback, yet does nothing.
  $db->rollBack();  
}
```

Now, the reason I found this to not be working is I exceeded the character limit on a row during a test to make sure all the logic in place was correct.

It did not rollback.  On top of that the record with 'single_item', was in the database.  But the updated values, were not.

Am I completely missing something small, I've never had transaction issues with MySQL & innoDB.  Could this be MySQL related or ZF related?  Any insight is helpful, thanks.

**Update:**

I've been conducting a few more tests and here are a few results that might help:

```
    $this->_db->beginTransaction();

    // This works
    $this->_db->insert('table_a', 
        array(
           'a_field' => 'transaction test',
        )
    );

    // This does not work, at all.  It inserts and does not rollback.  There is no commit.
    $_table_a_model->insert(
        array(
            'a_field' => 'transaction test',
        )
    );

    $this->_db->rollback();
```

**Additional Update**
You need to get the instance of the model, and call a transaction on that.

```
$the_model = $this->_model->getAdapter();
$the_model->beginTransaction();
```

This leaves no room for transactions for multiple tables, without doing multiple transactions for each model instance.  Any ideas out there without reverting to the base database instance?

Comment: Are any of the $model_record->foo() methods actually causing an exception to fire?

Comment: They do not. Everything works correctly if no exceptions fire.  The exception I'm getting is one directly from MySQL.

Comment: I just tested by using correct data, threw an exception before the commit();  Did not rollback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  I have to use `$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();` and then run my transactions off that so all operations in multiple models work together under a single transaction.  If anyone has a fix for that, feel free to comment.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much! But.... why is it so? Any explanation?
In my Bootstrap.php I created $db and saved it into Zend_Registry AND I set it as Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db). So why it's not working after I pull this object from registry and use it? Your solution works perfect !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your test case, exceeding the max chars just truncates the data inserted and does not in fact raise an exception?  Assuming that if you do something like mistype the name of a table you will get an exception (if not definitely check PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION is enabled).  If you are truly raising an exception that catch block should fire and rollback, if the commit is instead firing and you never call rollback() it sounds like the result is what you should expect.

Oh, and looking at your code suppose we should make sure that $db is the same instance in your model class as on that controller.  Look [here](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/mysql-transactions-in-zend-framework/) and see how same $db handle is used throughout.

**Edit:**
@Wes figured it out. "I have to use $db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter(); and then run my transactions off that so all operations in multiple models work together under a single transaction. If anyone has a fix for that, feel free to comment."

Comment: I assure you, it throws an exception through mysql and it is in fact caught.  Doesn't seem to make a difference.  The same functionality if all the transaction items are gone.

Comment: Updated the question with additional results.

Comment: Seems to me if you are getting the adapter from a singleton pattern you should be able to avoid this.  My 'models' in ZF usually pull the adapter from the Registry using a protected method on my base mapper class `$db = Zend_Registry::get($this->getAdapterName());`

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing, no dice.

Comment: my models all extend from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Comment: Beats me.  Must not be getting same instance of `$db` (Db_Adapter) or all this time you fat fingered something and this table is in fact MyISAM :)  I mean everything I've [read](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/DB-transactions-and-Zend-Db-Table-td670868.html) and looking at my own code indicates this should work fine.

Comment: Sure isn't, I'm sure it's something small I'm not thinking of.  But I sure hate to have 3 transactions running side by side in one method.

Comment: ficuscr you were the only one to help me out with this.  If you post my answer, I'll upvote you and mark it correct.  Cheers, Wes

Comment: Cheers.  Updated my original answer.